# Addons not working selenium driver (Firefox)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon

I created a Firefox profile an manually installed "HTTPS Everyhwere" and "uBlock Origin". but when using the selenium driver loading said profile the addons do not work.even though they are installed and active.
[image: Page with ads]

[image: Addon management screen]

So, what's happening? The thing is that it seemed to work fine at first, but it appears that after I manually blocked some elements with ublock, the addons stop working, could that be the cause?

Here's the code, its very basic:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox( executable_path= geckopath, firefox_profile= profile)
driver.get('https://www.nba.com')
```

So I checked which profile the selinium driver was running on and it was creating temporary profiles. I tripled check the path of the profile I want it to run on and it was correct. So for some reason it refuses to load the profile.

Comment: webdriver.Firefox( executable_path= geckopath, firefox_profile= <profile>) what is profile in this Line? is it object of FirefoxProfile class or just the Profile Name?

Comment: It's the path for the Firefox profile

Comment: If its a Path it should be working.Did you give the full path of the profile?

Comment: I use windows machine and I gave my Path like this"C:/ravi/profle/test.test" and its working

Comment: Are you getting any error when you are trying to run the program? If Yes,Could you please post the error?

Comment: No I'm not getting any erros, and the path is correct. The screenshots are from the driver running, so we can see that the addons are installed in the profile but they are not doing their job.

Comment: My Addons are working fine. How are you saying that your addons are not working? is there any difference in the page that is loaded when the addon s working and not working? Also can you please check if you have white listed the site?

Comment: In the first image I attached the first two banners are ads that don't load with ublock working, I've also tested with other sites and ads loads like there isn't an adblock installed. And no, there aren't any whitelist sites.

Comment: So i checked which profile the selinium driver was running on and it was creating temporary profiles. I tripled check the path of the profile I want it to run on and it was correct. So for some reason it refuses to load the profile.

Comment: Can you please paste the full code along with path of profile?

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:/Users/Python/geckodriver', firefox_profile= 'C:/Users/Windows10/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/cymy09hs.gecko')
driver.get('https://www.nba.com')

Comment: Weirdly its working for me on my Ubuntu and windows machines. Just out of curiosity don't you have to give .exe also in the executable path argument. anyways that might not be causing the issue because its launching the browser.Can you please once try with backslashes. I tried with both back slashes and forward slashes it worked for me using both. but just try changing to backslash once

Comment: I had already tried using both "\\" and "/" same result. Tried giving .exe to the path but the outcome was the same too. Also thanks for still trying to help me.

Comment: What is the version of selenium you are using? and also what is the version of firefox?

Comment: Also Can you please try other methods to launch a profile?
--Example
from selenium import webdriver
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/home/gabriel/.mozilla/firefox/whatever.selenium')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)

Comment: from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

options = Options()
options.add_argument("-profile")
options.add_argument("/home/gabriel/.mozilla/firefox/whatever.selenium")
firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities, firefox_options=options)

Comment: So I'm using Selenium 3.141.0 and Firefox  76.0.1.

The first approach yield the same results. The second one the browser opened and the profile load correctly, but the driver doesn't get any urls, and I get  the following error message: " selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: connection refused"